# jekyll don't show where error occurred

Tags: jekyll

Somehow, suddenly jekyll spit out an encoding error though i didn't do anything.

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll- 3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:290:in `join': incompatible character encodings: 
CP949 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll- 3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:290:in `block (2 levels) in safe_glob'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll- 3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:290:in `map'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:290:in `block in safe_glob'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:289:in `chdir'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:289:in `safe_glob'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/cleaner.rb:44:in `existing_files'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/cleaner.rb:25:in `obsolete_files'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/cleaner.rb:15:in `cleanup!'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:200:in `cleanup'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:70:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:26:in `process_site'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:63:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.5/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

Jekyll just shown "error is occurred". I want to make jekyll show me where error occurred, specifically a file name or line number.

Answer (score 0):

Starting development server with the --trace flag, it will give you the full backtrace every time an error happens.

```
 jekyll serve --trace
```

Comment: @RedLaboratory it will print the error as soon as it happens